# vaadin10.Session plugin location

Tags: vaadin

I'm new to web development. In some VaadinOnKotlin examples I see this code

```
import eu.vaadinonkotlin.vaadin8.Session
```

This is resolved by:

```
plugins {
    id("com.vaadin") version "0.8.0"
}
```

In other examples I see this code:

```
import eu.vaadinonkotlin.vaadin10.Session
```

How does this get resolved? In https://jcenter.bintray.com/eu/vaadinonkotlin/ I don't see any entries for vaadin10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important warning ahead: you are right to be suspicious about the
8 and 10+ versions - they use a fundamentally different tech-stack, but
share some similar APIs.  So always make sure, to look at the correct
tutorials.

Next, the dependency you are looking for is in:

```
eu.vaadinonkotlin:vok-util-vaadin10:$version
```

You need this as an *dependency* and *not* as a *plugin* (your assumption about the plugin is wrong here).  The plugin is needed too and is actually from the same author, but it's use is to allow the build tool, Gradle, to prepare for some ceremony for building development and production builds.

E.g. check out [this template
project](https://github.com/mvysny/beverage-buddy-vok/blob/master/build.gradle.kts) to or one of the other mentioned to get going without to much hastle in setting things up.

Comment: Very clear explanation. My problem has been resolved. Thank you!